# Is there any wmctrl alternatives on OS X?

Tags: macos, wmctrl

Is there an alternative of wmctrl on OS X? It seems that wmctrl (installed from Homebrew) only works for X Applications on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some of the things wmctrl can do on OS X via AppleScript. [Here is an example](http://blog.viktorkelemen.com/2011/07/resize-and-position-windows-with.html).

Do some research into AppleScript. It can be very useful.

Also, there is an application called [stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/). Definitely doesn't have near as many options as wmctrl, but who knows, it might be all you need.

**Edit:**

Per askers request, here is a free one! [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt). I still recommend AppleScript, it is the hardest of the three to master, but it is also the most powerful.

Comment: Thanks! I would prefer something free. I guess I'll go with AppleScript.